# Must a Revel application have an app folder to organize its code?

Tags: go, revel

revel new revel-svr1 :

revel-svr

```
 ----app
        -----controllers
        -----views
```

i create revel application revel-svr1,   it creates app folder which contains controller and views etc...,    if i delete app folder, it shows:

revel-svr

```
 ----controllers
 ----views
```

it does not work,  Does app folder must exists？

Comment: Yes. When I check the documentation, it says "Revel will watch all directories under app/ and rebuild when it notices any changes."
https://revel.github.io/manual/organization.html

Comment: @mk, thank you for you answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://revel.github.io/manual/organization.html

> The app/ directory contains the source code and templates for your application.
>
> app/controllers/ - All controllers are required here
>
> app/views - All templates are required here

So yes you must keep the /app directory